# few confusion regarding ORM

Tags: php, mysql, orm

i have few confusion regarding ORM(Object Relational Mapping)

i am thinking about to use ORM in my upcoming website (Social Network)

1. Is ORM faster way to access/manipulate database?
2. how do i call procedure or function if i use ORM.
3. Is it good idea to use ORM for social networking site where traffic may be high (200 user may access website concurrently)(i am sure user can not greater than 10 000)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please don't take it as offence, but if the only thing you're concerned with is what performance penalty you might get by using ORM, you're already doing it wrong. )

Actually there's a plenty of factors to take into account. The tags suggest you intend to use PHP-MySQL combination in your project. But do you really *know* these tools - or you want to learn them in process?

If latter, I'd definitely recommend using ORM *no matter what* - but not a standalone one. I suggest building your project on an established (and well-documented) MVC framework  instead - and using its ORM. See, it's one thing to work with ORM as with an abstract concept - and another to *use it* as a tool in the context of a specific framework.

What framework to choose, that's another question; I really suggest looking at [Symfony 2](http://symfony.com/what-is-symfony) - it's integrated with a really powerful ORM library (Doctrine), but you still can use direct queries if you need it. )

P.S. I suggest reading this [brilliant post](http://java.dzone.com/articles/martin-fowler-orm-hate) of Martin Fowler: it's not so much about 'ORM hate', instead focusing mostly on how ORM should be perceived in general.

Answer (score 1):

> Is ORM faster way to access/manipulate database?

In general, an ORM will reduce development time and maintenance effort in exchange for reduced runtime performance. (Performance loss is not usually significant).

> how do i call procedure or function if i use ORM.

That depends on the specific ORM

> Is it good idea to use ORM for social networking site where traffic may be high

Yes.

Answer (score 1):

1. No in terms of performance, yes in terms of coding effort
2. Same as if you don't use it... please be clearer on this
3. Hell yes!

Comment: i think it will be better i go with framework or traditional php

Comment: yes, frameworks for sure, coding php without one is a nightmare